# Depthwise stacking with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using the following code and getting an output numpy ndarray of size (2,9) that I am then trying to reshape into size (3,3,2). My hope was that calling reshape using (3,3,2) as the dimensions of the new array would take each *row* of the 2x9 array and shape it into a 3x3 array and wrap these two 3x3 arrays into another array.

For instance, when I index the **result** I would like the following behavior:

```
input: print(result)
output: [[ 2.  2.  1.  0.  8.  5.  2.  4.  5.]
         [ 4.  7.  5.  6.  4.  3. -3.  2.  1.]]

result = result.reshape((3,3,2))

DESIRED NEW BEHAVIOR
input: print(result[:,:,0])
output: [[2. 2. 1.]
         [0. 8. 5.]
         [2. 4. 5.]]

input: print(result[:,:,1])
output: [[ 4.  7.  5.]
         [ 6.  4.  3.]
         [-3.  2.  1.]]

ACTUAL NEW BEHAVIOR
input: print(result[:,:,0])
output: [[2. 1. 8.]
         [2. 5. 7.]
         [6. 3. 2.]]

input: print(result[:,:,1])
output: [[ 2.  0.  5.]
         [ 4.  4.  5.]
         [ 4. -3.  1.]]
```

Is there a way to specify to reshape that I would like to go row by row along the depth dimension? I'm very confused as to why numpy by default makes the choice it does for reshape.

Here is the code I am using to produce **result** matrix, this code may or may not be necessary to analyze my issue. I feel as if it will not be necessary but am including it for completeness:

```
import numpy as np

# im2col implementation assuming width/height dimensions of filter and input_vol
# are the same (i.e. input_vol_width is equal to input_vol_height and the same
# for the filter spatial dimensions, although input_vol_width need not equal
# filter_vol_width)

def im2col(input, filters, input_vol_dims, filter_size_dims, stride):
    receptive_field_size = 1
    for dim in filter_size_dims:
        receptive_field_size *= dim

    output_width = output_height = int((input_vol_dims[0]-filter_size_dims[0])/stride + 1)

    X_col = np.zeros((receptive_field_size,output_width*output_height))

    W_row = np.zeros((len(filters),receptive_field_size))

    pos = 0
    for i in range(0,input_vol_dims[0]-1,stride):
        for j in range(0,input_vol_dims[1]-1,stride):
           X_col[:,pos] = input[i:i+stride+1,j:j+stride+1,:].ravel()
           pos += 1

    for i in range(len(filters)):
        W_row[i,:] = filters[i].ravel()

    bias = np.array([[1], [0]])

    result = np.dot(W_row, X_col) + bias

    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.zeros((7, 7, 3))

    x[:,:,0] = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         [0,1,1,0,0,1,0],
                         [0,2,2,1,1,1,0],
                         [0,2,0,2,1,0,0],
                         [0,2,0,0,1,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

    x[:,:,1] = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         [0,2,0,1,0,2,0],
                         [0,0,1,2,1,0,0],
                         [0,2,0,0,2,0,0],
                         [0,2,1,0,0,0,0],
                         [0,1,2,2,2,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

    x[:,:,2] = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,2,1,1,0],
                         [0,0,0,2,2,0,0],
                         [0,2,1,0,2,2,0],
                         [0,0,1,2,1,2,0],
                         [0,2,0,0,2,1,0],
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

    w0 = np.zeros((3,3,3))

    w0[:,:,0] = np.array([[1,1,0],
                          [1,-1,1],
                          [-1,1,1]])

    w0[:,:,1] = np.array([[-1,-1,0],
                          [1,-1,1],
                          [1,-1,-1]])

    w0[:,:,2] = np.array([[0,0,0],
                          [0,0,1],
                          [1,0,1]]


    w1 = np.zeros((3,3,3))

    w1[:,:,0] = np.array([[0,-1,1],
                         [1,1,0],
                         [1,1,0]])

    w1[:,:,1] = np.array([[-1,-1,1],
                          [1,0,1],
                          [0,1,1]])

    w1[:,:,2] = np.array([[-1,-1,0],
                          [1,-1,0],
                          [1,1,0]])


    filters = np.array([w0,w1])

    im2col(x,np.array([w0,w1]),x.shape,w0.shape,2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's reshape a bit differently and then do a depth-wise `dstack`:

```
arr = np.dstack(result.reshape((-1,3,3)))
```

```
arr[..., 0]
array([[2., 2., 1.],
       [0., 8., 5.],
       [2., 4., 5.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Reshape keeps the original order of the elements

```
In [215]: x=np.array(x)
In [216]: x.shape
Out[216]: (2, 9)
```

Reshaping the size 9 dimension into a 3x3 keeps the element order that you want:

```
In [217]: x.reshape(2,3,3)
Out[217]: 
array([[[ 2.,  2.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  8.,  5.],
        [ 2.,  4.,  5.]],

       [[ 4.,  7.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  4.,  3.],
        [-3.,  2.,  1.]]])
```

But you have to index it with `[0,:,:]` to see one of those blocks.

To see the same blocks with [:,:,0], you have to move that size 2 dimension to the end.  `COLDSPEED's` `dstack` does that by iterating on the first dimension, and joining the 2 blocks (each 3x3) on a new third dimension).  Another way is to use `transpose` to reorder the dimensions:

```
In [218]: x.reshape(2,3,3).transpose(1,2,0)
Out[218]: 
array([[[ 2.,  4.],
        [ 2.,  7.],
        [ 1.,  5.]],

       [[ 0.,  6.],
        [ 8.,  4.],
        [ 5.,  3.]],

       [[ 2., -3.],
        [ 4.,  2.],
        [ 5.,  1.]]])
In [219]: y = _
In [220]: y.shape
Out[220]: (3, 3, 2)
In [221]: y[:,:,0]
Out[221]: 
array([[2., 2., 1.],
       [0., 8., 5.],
       [2., 4., 5.]])
```